# Can I use ConditionObject instead of getting it from a lock?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, wait, notify

Every source i saw in the www states that a `Condition Object` is get by using the `newCondition method` on a `Lock object`

```
ReentrantLock.newCondition()
```

But by navigating the java sources i saw that a implementation is already available.

```
ConditionObject // implements Condition
```

I dont want to be the only one but thats why I am asking.

Can I Use this Condition Object to wait/notify/notifyAll with synchronized methods?

Or is it any better to stick to the combination with locks?

Additionally:

There is so much code in the `await() method` of a `Condition object`. Could there by a performance difference between the traditional wait/notify/notifyAll?

Comment: It's not the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where did you find that `ConditionObject`, but it's most likely some internal object used by a lock class.

Condition cannot exist by itself without a lock (a monitor, to be precise), that's because await/signal need access to that monitor.
When you call `await` method it'll put current thread on the wait list of the monitor, suspends it (parks it, so it's excluded from scheduling) and it'll release the lock, so that other threads can acquire it.
When you call `signal`, then one thread in the wait list of the monitor is being resumed.

Comment: Oh yes, totally forgot about the temporarily unlock mechanism here. But the newCondition method still returns a new ConditionObject at the end. It's a public class inside AbstractQueuedSynchronizer

Comment: It's a public class, but not a static class. So you still need reference to `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` to create its instance.

Comment: Not to mention that `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` needs to be subclassed to use conditions, as with `ReentrantReadWriteLock.Sync`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's give a conceptual answer here:

> But by navigating the java sources i saw that a implementation is already available.

In other words: should your code that uses a public standard API rely on an **internal implementation detail** of that API?

The answer to that is (almost) always: **of course not**!

You make your code dependant on the contracts that the public API provides, not at all on how it is implemented. Thing is, (at least theoretically) such internal implementation details can change with any new version of Java. Sure, if it is a structural thing then the compiler might tell you, but what if not?

Meaning: when you study java standard library code, then to improve your overall knowledge on programming (one can learn a lot from reading and thinking about this code). But unless you have very good reasons to do so: never ever let the *internals* guide your code!

Answer (score -1):

You can't use it without its associated lock. `ConditionObject` is connected to `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` which can be used to create locks, semaphores and other things so you don't need to worry about the details.

You've been given easy to use concurrency primitives in `java.util.concurrent.locks` package. I recommend you use them, you have less chance of getting things wrong that way.